# How to run Vagrant/Virtualbox on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, virtualbox

I wrote a unittest that verifies the setup of my dev environment by using Vagrant to create a Virtualbox VM and then run through all the setup steps.

I'm not trying to run this unittest as part of my normal build process on a QA server running as an EC2 instance, and it's failing because EC2 is based on Xen and Virtualbox doesn't support Xen. Trying to install the latest Oracle Virtualbox with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1` fails with the error:

```
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported.
```

Oddly, installing the vanilla Virtualbox package in Ubuntu's standard repo succeeds, although it doesn't provide the VBoxManage tool needed by Vagrant.

What's the easiest way to get Vagrant to be able to spin up a VM from inside an EC2 instance? Presumably, I could use an EC2 provider, but spinning up an EC2 instance over the network is much much slower and more complicated than creating a local instance.